# Get changed files from svn command line between two timestamps

Tags: linux, svn, diff

Getting changed files from svn command line between two dates is possible.

Eg: `svn diff -r{2014-01-06}:{2014-08-06} --summarize svn-path`

But how about getting changed files from svn between two date & time stamp combination?

Eg., something like  this
`svn diff -r{2014-01-06 13:56:19}:{2014-08-06 22:40:01} --summarize svn-path`

Is this possible in SVN on linux platform?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. Apache Subversion accepts ISO-8601 date and time formats and some others. See `--revision` option's description in [SVNBook | Revision Dates](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.tour.revs.specifiers.html#svn.tour.revs.dates).

Here is the command you look for

`svn diff -r{"2014-01-06 13:56"}:{"2014-08-06 22:40"} --summarize svn-path`

Here is the list of format examples:

```
svn update -r {2006-02-17}
svn update -r {15:30}
svn update -r {15:30:00.200000}
svn update -r {"2006-02-17 15:30"}
svn update -r {"2006-02-17 15:30 +0230"}
svn update -r {2006-02-17T15:30}
svn update -r {2006-02-17T15:30Z}
svn update -r {2006-02-17T15:30-04:00}
svn update -r {20060217T1530}
svn update -r {20060217T1530Z}
svn update -r {20060217T1530-0500}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [time in timestamp-spec](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.tour.revs.specifiers.html#svn.tour.revs.dates) inside Subversion on any platform, in more than single format